# Indexing a data file created from node.js using elastic search

Tags: node.js, indexing, elasticsearch

I have created a csv file by reading a table from an html file. I have written script in node.js for creating this csv file.
Now, I have to index the fields in elastic search.
I dont know about elastic search and I need your help to figure this out
In my CSV file, I have 3 fields(name, buy, sell).

Answer (score 0):

A nice thing about Elasticsearch is in many cases, you can just throw data at it and it will figure out how to index it for you.

Using the [official library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js), you can do:

```
var documents = // read from csv

client.bulk({
  body: documents.map(document => [
    { index: { _index: 'myindex', _type: 'mytype', _id: 'documentid' } },
    // the document to index
    document
  ]).flatten()
}).then(response => {
  // ...
});
```

Elasticsearch will automatically create a mapping for your fields so you will be able to search:

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  type: 'mytype',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        name: 'joe'
      }
    }
  }
}).then(response => {
  var hits = body.hits.hits;
}).catch(error => {
  console.trace(error.message);
});
```